# access multiple html data attributes with jQuery 'this'

Tags: jquery, this, html

Ok, the title might be a little confusing. Let me explain.

```
<div class="book">
    <h3>Name of Book</h3>
    <p>
        <span data-notmobile="Author"></span>Rajesh K. Maurya</p>
    <p>
        <span data-notmobile="Publication"></span>Wiley India</p>
    <p>
        <span data-notmobile="Edition"></span>2011</p>
    <p>
        <span data-notmobile="Branch"></span>Information Technology</p>
    <p>
        <span data-notmobile="Semester"></span>5</p>
</div>
```

Now I want a way to swap out the content of each span with its data attribute respectively.
I tried

```
$('.book span').html($('.book span').data("notmobile"));
```

which only changes the inner html to the first attribute ie "Author". For some reason, the 'this' keyword does not work.

I want to do this without giving each span a class of its own.

Comment: PS. Where's "this" in your code..?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.book span').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).data("notmobile"));
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqM9C/)

Comment: @supernoob. No problem. I added a demo, hope you like it.

Answer (score 2):

`$('.book span').data('notmobile')` returns the value of the first matching element. Use the following code to get the correct desired effect:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gezxj/

```
$('.book span').html(function() {
    return $(this).data("notmobile");
});
```

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Gezxj/1/) fiddle is easy to get. just added css to your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.book span').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.data('notmobile')); 
});
```